# After change server from another , Admin Login Page Error : 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, installation

I upload my magento store on server from other server.but when try to login in admin panel I get 404 error .
what is the solution ?

I go into the `phpmyadmin` and also check for below `code`

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

so what is the problem, i can not debug...

Comment: Can you double check what your `frontName` is within `app/etc/local.xml`? That should be the URL of the admin panel

Comment: yes , both are same admin

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Comment: what I need to check in .htaccess file